# Apollo pagination with vuex

Tags: vue.js, graphql, nuxt.js

I'm trying to get vuetify's pagination component to work with the [nuxtjs@apollo module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/apollo-module).

But I'm having a hard time getting it to work with my vuex store.

I'll skip over most of the code as its a lot of boilerplate.

First of all in order to populate my initial state I send a graphql query to my back end and commit these to my state.

```js
const client = context.app.apolloProvider.defaultClient

const response = await client.query({
  query: productsGQL,
  variables: {
    first: 5,
    page: 1
  }
})

commit('setProducts', response.data.products.data)
commit('setPagination', response.data.products.paginatorInfo)
commit('setPage', response.data.products.paginatorInfo.currentPage)
```

this works fine, products, pagination and page are all set with initial data.

Now, I have 2 components a `CardComponent` that contains all of the products like so

```html
<script>
export default {
  name: 'CardComponent',

  computed: {
    products() {
      return this.$store.getters.getProducts
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

And a `PaginationComponent`:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <v-pagination
      v-model='page'
      circle
      :length='total_pages'
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'PaginationComponent',

  data() {
    return {
      total_pages: Math.ceil(this.$store.getters.getPagination.total / this.$store.getters.getPagination.perPage)
    }
  },

  computed: {
    page: {
      get() {
        return this.$store.getters.getPage
      },
      set(value) {
        return this.$store.commit('setPage', value)
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

`Page` Initial value is 1, when I click on the second page the `Page` variable is updated to 2,  this is also than reflected in my state.

The thing I'm unsure about is: how do I `requery` the database? the page is being updated but the products displayed are still the same, and I'm not sure how to go about this.

If you some more code from the store I'll show it here.

Comment: If your state is okay (double check your devtools, both Vue and Apollo ones) and the only thing missing, is another call to the database (double check your network tab), you could probably use the `refresh()` method as shown here: https://apollo.vuejs.org/api/smart-query.html#refresh

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply. but yes it was indeed the `refresh()` method that needed to be called again. Thanks for  the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `refresh()` fixed the issue: https://apollo.vuejs.org/api/smart-query.html#refresh